# Inconsistency between STM32H7 AES HAL and Reference Manual

Tags: c, aes, stm32

I'm starting to implement AES-GCM on STM32H753 (rev V).

I've found an inconsistency between the HAL and the Ref Manual.

The STMicro HAL for AES for STM32H7x3 is setting some bits called `NPBLB` in `CRYP_CR` register if the product revision is above rev B.

But these bits are not documented in the ref manual rev 7.

Is it just an error of the HAL ?

Comment: What does STMicro say? They should know.

Comment: Well "they" do not answer any question you ask :) the reference manual is for me the reference but I's like to be sure

Comment: Have you read the errata?

Comment: I can't find anything in the published errata related to this, but from experience, ST do not always publicize silicon (or software) bugs until they are hurting a large customer or two.  It may be best to duplicate the behaviour in your code.

Comment: yes it is not in the errata. It's not a silicon bug though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for the IP blocks to be shared between different STM32 families, so if you cannot find info in the reference manual of your device, it is [worth looking at the documentation of other devices](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g73.html).

[AN5312](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5312-migration-from-revy-to-revv-for-stm32h743753-and-stm32h750-value-line-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) mentions that NPBLB bits were added in revision V, but gives no documentation about the meaning of the bits:

> RevV supports hardware management for GCM encryption or CCM decryption
> with the last block of payload size inferior to 128 bits. This is
> possible thanks to the addition of the NPBLB bit field (the
> highlighted cells in Figure 5) in the CRYP_CR register.

The [reference manual of STM32MP1](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0436-stm32mp157-advanced-armbased-32bit-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), however, has the description of these bits, as shown below:

[image: CRYP_CR]